# How do you make an ElasticBeanStalk's Enviroment use a RDS instance seperate from the one that was created when the enviroment was launched?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I tried following the instruction from [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.RDS.html?console_help=true) but it seems to be outdated!

I followed all the instructions specifically and most importantly: I added the detached RDS instance security group name(called default) to the Enviroment's Security group. I created the necessary environment name like `RDS_HOSTNAME`, `RDS_USERNAME` etc.

I can ssh into the detached RDS instance via the eb shell, so the instance is working. However, the elastic Beanstalk's environment name `RDS_HOSTNAME` seems to still reference the RDS hostname that was automatically created with the environment despite that RDS instance being deleted.

Comment: what does `eb config` output with regards to the RDS? Did you try to copy the configuration and update the RDS configuration details then load the updated configuration file?

Comment: This is what is says regarding rds:  aws:rds:dbinstance:
    DBAllocatedStorage: '5'
    DBDeletionPolicy: Snapshot
    DBInstanceClass: db.t2.micro
    DBSnapshotIdentifier: null
    MultiAZDatabase: 'false'

Comment: Have you tried setting the `RDS_HOSTNAME` variable to the new RDS host? Also very that `eb printenv` shows this variable.

Comment: It sounds like you created an attached RDS database when you created your EB instance, and now are trying to replace it with another instance. You should not have done that. Create the EB instance with no associated RDS instance, create an RDS instance manually, and then set the five `RDS_` environment variables and everything should be fine.

Comment: @progfan I did, but that doesn't seem to change the endpoint where the EC2 instance looks for the database endpoint.